# Can I call other methods in other javascript files from my overlay script?

Tags: javascript, firefox, file, firefox-addon

I am writing a Firefox extension. I have setup an overlay for `chrome://browser/content/browser.xul` and I am handling the on load event.  This I have working.

I also have N separate .js files in my extension (specifically in `chrome://my-extension/content/js/*.js`).  Each of these .js files implements a common interface.

For example, `foo.js` might look like this:

```
var fooThinger = {
  doYouCare: function (e) {
    // ... decide if I care ...
    return cares;
  },
  someOtherStuff: function (e) {
    // ... some other stuff ...
  },
  // ... other methods ...
}

function getThinger() {
  return new fooThinger();
}
```

What I can do is enumerate all of these .js files in my browser on load handler, which I can do using [nsIFile](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Code_snippets/File_I//O) and all that.

What I **don't know** how to do is call the `getThinger()` method in each file once I've built up a list of all the files in the directory.  Is this possible?  If so, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you would use either https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Components.utils.import or mozIJSSubScriptLoader which is described on the same page. I'm not sure which one is better for your case.

Comment: Looks reasonable.  I'll give that a shot (`mozIJSSubScriptLoader`).